# Turned lables off in tf in rqt rivz and started getting this error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I turned of labels in rviz running under rqt and got this error . Any idea  what this is?

```
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_runtime_monitor/runtime_monitor_widget.py", line 320, in _on_timer
    self._update_root_labels()
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_runtime_monitor/runtime_monitor_widget.py", line 336, in _update_root_labels
    self._stale_node.setText(0, "Stale (%s)" % (self._stale_node.childCount()))
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QTreeWidgetItem has been deleted
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81541/turned-lables-off-in-tf-in-rqt-rivz-and-started-getting-this-error./) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue has not reoccurred for some time now. Will close as too localized.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2013-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0